# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Design.Server

Tags: sharepoint-2010, tfsbuild

Help please, I am having an error on the TFS. it complains that it cannot load the assembly below.
the project works fine on my computer. I searched for the dll by there is no such dll called: Microsoft.Web.Design.Server.

Any help pelase?

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Design.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'

Comment: Have you installed [SharePoint 2010 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12323) on the build machine?

Comment: Hi KMoraz, I don't really know since it is TFS where I get the error. I will ask the gusy for it. Let you know. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The build server does not have the same software installed as your local machine.  Thus when it goes to resolve dependencies it cannot find them.

This is compounded when your project has GAC references.

I recommend that anything which isn't a system assembly be copied to a folder and put into source control.  The projects should then reference this assembly as a file reference instead of a GAC reference.

Since the file is now in source control it'll be available to the build server for it to resolve the assembly at compile time.